# Chatroom writing exercises - log

Tags: discussion, chat, writing-exercise

A place to link to writing exercise chats. One answer per chat session should work well, rather than having a new thread every week.

These are CW, so anyone can edit their stories into this.

#### List of chat sessions

- [14 October 2014. Topic: Bully](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/a/923)
- [7 October 2014. Topic: The darkest days of my life.](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/a/924)
- [30 September 2014. Topic: Rescue Reward](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/a/905)
- [23 September 2014. Topic: Cheese crackers](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/a/897)
- [16 September 2014. Topic: The Wild Flute](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/a/921)
- [9 September 2014. Topic: A good adventure story](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/a/922)
- [2 September 2014. Topic: High School Crush](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/a/920)
- [13 May 2014. Topic: Limericks (informal)](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/a/896)
- [25 March 2014. Topic: The untouched coffee](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/a/898)

Answer (score 1):

**May 2014. Topic: Limericks (informal)**

Participants:

- [Lauren](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/15502667#15502667)
- [Paul A.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/15502855#15502855)
- [Kitfox](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/15502876#15502876)
- [Mr. Shiny](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/15503029#15503029)
- [Matt Эллен](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/15503323#15503323)
- [Neil](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/15514510#15514510)
- [Cornbread](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/15514723#15514723)

Answer (score 1):

**23 Sep 2014. Topic: Cheese crackers**

- [Neil](http://neilfein.tumblr.com/post/98822776569/writing-exercise-23sep2014-cheese-crackers)
- [Matt Эллен](http://sgdi.tumblr.com/post/98249161383/grandmas-advice)
- [Arrowfar](http://arrowfar.wordpress.com/2014/09/23/cheese-crackers/)

Answer (score 1):

**March 2014 week 4 - The untouched coffee**

Facilitator: [Pravesh Parekh](https://writers.stackexchange.com/users/5909/pravesh-parekh)

Available Users: [Neil Fein](https://writers.stackexchange.com/users/26/neil-fein), [prateek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1503130/prateek), [Matt Eckert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/774071/matt-eckert)

Participated: [Neil Fein](https://writers.stackexchange.com/users/26/neil-fein) and [Pravesh Parekh](https://writers.stackexchange.com/users/5909/pravesh-parekh)

[Link to conversation](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/168/conversation/weekly-writing-chat-2014-03-25) (courtesy [Monica Cellio](https://writers.stackexchange.com/users/1993/monica-cellio))

---

- [Posted by Pravesh](http://requiem-for-a-lost-soul.blogspot.in/2011/06/cup-of-coffee.html)
  (was not a fresh written piece, something from June 2011 shared because of similar context)
- [Posted by Neil](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/14479626#14479626)

Answer (score 1):

**30 Sep 2014**

"Rescue Reward"

- [neilfein](http://neilfein.tumblr.com/post/98820602169/writing-exercise-30sep2014-rescue-reward)
- [Aaron](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1g0HfG4AlARIF-8uUA1siogAVa4J3cxS401lPnEHsaO4/edit)
- [Mr. Shiny and New 安宇](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1DLRBQgmOOiBQh8Ch8oBBYoEx2cO6HIgNcJkEcbwhx3E/)
- [Arrowfar](http://arrowfar.wordpress.com/2014/09/30/rescue-reward/)
- [Matt Эллен](http://sgdi.tumblr.com/post/98821939508/now-see-here-said-dave-it-says-youll-give-me)

Answer (score 0):

**2 September 2014 - High School Crush**

- [KitFox](http://foxfirekitty.wordpress.com/2014/09/02/lightning-rounds-28/)
- [Neil](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=CUZCQ7Dg)
- [Arrowfar](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/168?m=17466425#17466425)
- [Matt](http://sgdi.tumblr.com/post/96471781953/somehow-she-knew-my-name-of-course-i-knew-hers)
- [Monica](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/168?m=17493705#17493705)
- [Mr Shiny and New](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1RouGdejQYwHeKOR4-_DUbgmDBKp1diCSUpwG578qn2g/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

**16 September 2014 - The Wild Flute**

- [Will Hunting](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/168?m=17702824#17702824)
- [KitFox](http://foxfirekitty.wordpress.com/2014/09/16/lightning-rounds-29/)
- [Aaron](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1PrEyARV6xYpNc5_KaV3wREz4n74FtVWGr6Ey4EWbfdQ/edit?usp=sharing)
- [Mr. Shiny and New](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/168?m=17703406#17703406)
- [Arrowfar](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/168?m=17703515#17703515)

Answer (score 0):

#### 9 September 2014. Topic: A good adventure story

- [Arrowfar](http://arrowfar.wordpress.com/2014/09/16/a-good-adventure-story/)
- [Matt Эллен](http://sgdi.tumblr.com/post/97075037088/they-were-sat-around-the-camp-fire-daniel-looked)

Answer (score 0):

#### 14 October 2014. Topic: Bully

- [KitFox](http://foxfirekitty.wordpress.com/2014/10/14/lightning-rounds-31/)
- [MattЭллен](http://sgdi.tumblr.com/post/100006075223/always-the-same-every-day-i-look-at-myself-and-i)
- [Aaron](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1_2UejE6Zv5aNQQld4xvdoDxHGyLZblRwnN7NVlZ_gdw/edit?usp=sharing)
- [Mr.ShinyandNew安宇](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1dUIe6JgCpiNzOZUA4AvtoQwg59kI09HY9Gk7VsxpXFc/edit)

Answer (score 0):

#### 7 October 2014. Topic: The darkest days of my life.

- [Jasper Loy](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18040376#18040376)
- [KitFox](http://foxfirekitty.wordpress.com/2014/10/07/lightning-rounds-30/)
- [Aaron](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1tioFcCsaw4ipHofiP56F75czWcDe14BygGPMXxYgUT8/edit?usp=sharing)
- [MattЭллен](http://sgdi.tumblr.com/post/99426841558/the-heat-of-the-sun-was-stronger-than-you-can)
- [Arrowfar](http://arrowfar.wordpress.com/2014/10/07/the-darkest-days-of-my-life/)